# passing parameter through url for edit part and getting back it in views

Tags: django

[image]how to  get  id from  url have strucked here please  guide  someone . After clicking edit it will  approach vendor def ...
i have 10 records in my db  . after  clicking  each  record's edit option  in  template it  should show that  particular  individual  record details . but  here im  facing  index page of  url after  clicking  edit  option.

my views.py

```
def vendor(request):
key = request.GET.get('id')
obj = vender.objects.get(id = key)
return  render_to_response('edit_vendor.html',  
    {'obj':obj},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in  template i am passing id  like this

```
 <a href ='vendor/id={{vendor.id}}'> edit </a>
```

im  able to  see  id in  url  when  i  click  edit option
my  url is

```
url(r'^vendor/(\id+)/$',vendor ),
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers given below?

Answer (score 1):

```
def vendor(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(vender, pk=id)
    ...........


<a href ='vendor/{{vendor.id}}/'> edit </a>


url(r'^vendor/(?P<id>\d+)/$',vendor ),
```

Comment: this problem  came to  end by  dong like this <a href ='/vendor/{{vendor.id}}/'>

Comment: this problem  came to  end by  dong like this <a href ='/vendor/{{vendor.id}}/'>                                                               thank  you for responding

Answer (score 1):

Django make's this type of thing easier on you.

In your urls.py:

```
(r'^vendor/(?P<vendor_id>\d+)/$', 'vendor', name='vender_detail'),
```

In your view:

```
def vendor(request, vendor_id = None, *args, **kwargs):
```

In your template:

```
<a href ='{% url "vendor_detail" vendor.id %}'> edit </a>
```

This assumes Django 1.5.

If you're using 1.4, do this in your template:

```
<a href ='{% url vendor_detail vendor.id %}'> edit </a>
```

Using the `url` template tag is a great way to decouple your templates from your URL patterns, allowing you to change the URL structure without having to go back and edit all your templates.

Comment: can  name can be anything  here ?   name='vender_detail'

Comment: Sure, just make sure you use the same name when you call it from the url template tag.

Answer (score 0):

In template:

```
<a href ='vendor/{{vendor.id}}/'> edit </a>
```

In `urls.py`:

```
(r'^manage_vendor/vendor/(?P<vendor_id>\d+)/$', 'vendor'),
```

In `views.py`:

```
def vendor(request, vendor_id = None):
    print vendor_id
```

Comment: Your `href` attribute points to `/vendor/{{ vendor.id }}/` and your browser screenshot shows the format `/manage_vendor/vendor/{{ vendor.id }}/`. Check it.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage_vendor/manage_vendor/vendor/11/   now  its showing  me like this

Comment: Are you sure that the anchor tag in your question is the same as in your template?

Comment: TypeError at /manage_vendor/vendor/10/
'str' object is not callable     --  new error now after correcting  everything  again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25125/discussion-between-arulmr-and-raghu)

Comment: Can you post your updated your code or join the above mentioned chat room to help you better?